# [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 & h10 error with mySQL, Nodejs, Express and Heroku

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, heroku, sequelize.js

I am following a tutorial about a full stack application through Reactjs, Nodejs, Express and MySQL, and am struggling with errors when trying to deploy the backend to Heroku.

I've searched through a bunch of similar issues on StackOverflow, but none seem to work for me. I will place the error code, my server.js/config.json/package.json files, and a detailed description of what I've done thus far to try to remedy it.

**The error in my terminal:**

```
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535599+00:00 app[web.1]: ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535615+00:00 app[web.1]: at ConnectionManager.connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:92:17)
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535615+00:00 app[web.1]: at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535616+00:00 app[web.1]: at async ConnectionManager._connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:220:24)
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535616+00:00 app[web.1]: at async /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535616+00:00 app[web.1]: at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:197:7)
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535618+00:00 app[web.1]: at async /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:304:26
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535618+00:00 app[web.1]: at async MySQLQueryInterface.tableExists (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:102:17)
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535618+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Albums.sync (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:939:21)
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535618+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Sequelize.sync (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:376:9) {
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535619+00:00 app[web.1]: parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535619+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535620+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535622+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535622+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535622+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535623+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 3306,
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535624+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: true
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535624+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535624+00:00 app[web.1]: original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535624+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535625+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535625+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535625+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535625+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535625+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 3306,
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535625+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: true
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535626+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535626+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2023-02-04T02:23:34.543110+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice
2023-02-04T02:23:34.543220+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.3.1 -> 9.4.1
2023-02-04T02:23:34.543597+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.4.1>
2023-02-04T02:23:34.543655+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.4.1` to update!
2023-02-04T02:23:34.543847+00:00 app[web.1]: npm notice
2023-02-04T02:23:34.680163+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2023-02-04T02:23:34.725119+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-02-04T02:23:36.383791+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sq-photos-api.herokuapp.com request_id=68108bed-86b9-4d92-9a08-5c693cd4f9e4 fwd="50.38.34.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-02-04T02:23:36.800226+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sq-photos-api.herokuapp.com request_id=1c4e1c2b-023c-4d9e-bc7b-3e4f24f0fb50 fwd="50.38.34.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**My server.js file**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
//For Heroku
require("dotenv").config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 6060;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
const db = require("./models");

//Routers
//Album Router
const albumRouter = require("./routes/Albums");
app.use("/albums", albumRouter);
//Teams Router
const teamRouter = require("./routes/Teams");
app.use("/teams", teamRouter);
//User Router
const userRouter = require("./routes/Users");
app.use("/auth", userRouter);

db.sequelize
  .sync()
  .then(() => {
    //Heroku runs process.env.PORT and our own port
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Server started on 6060`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

**My config.json file** (for security reasons, i changed my actual password to "password"

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "sq_photo_db",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

**My package.json** (to show that everything has been properly installed and scripts run correctly):

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "devStart": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "sequelize": "^6.28.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.0"
  }
}
```

While searching through the h10 error on Stack Overflow and Google, I've discovered that people had a similar issue. A common fix was to create a port variable in the server.js file and pass it through the listen function. Like so:

- `const port = process.env.PORT || 6060;` and passed it to through the app.listen() function, but that hasn't fixed the h10 error.

In the first line is a Sequelize error that says it cannot connect to my server, which is:

```
2023-02-04T02:23:34.535599+00:00 app[web.1]: ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

After searching this error, I tried these solutions:

- I checked if my MySQL server was still running, in the off-chance that maybe my Mac turned it off.  As you can see here, it is still running fine, even on start up. [Mac settings to show MySQL server is running properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQUYW.png)
- I have tried changing the "host" in the development object of my config.json to:
  `"host":"localhost"` after doing reading someones suggestion. But that didn't fix anything

I've spent the majority of the day trying to fix this and could use a little push in the right direction so I can get over this little hiccup. If anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: Your production `host` config cannot be `127.0.0.1`. It must be the host of production DB

Comment: Because I'm fairly new, is changing it from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`  what are you are referring to? When I go into the db settings on MySQL Workbench, I see that `localhost` is the designated host for the db. Or is there's something more specific within MySQL Workbench that I need to find and use that for the `host` in the `production` config

Comment: You should search on how to connect to MySQL on Heroku

Comment: The database setup is ok., this means the config.json is not read. Please include the code where you init database config, e.g: `models.js`

Comment: Configured the db and recognized there was some port issues on my own end, ended up changing that and it works. THanks for the help